# Determinant of a matrix constrained by conditions

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Let $A$ be a real $4 \times 4$ matrix such that $\operatorname{trace}(A) = 0$ and $A + xA^2 = I$, where $x \in \Bbb R$. Show that $$\det(A) = -\frac{16}{27}$$

---

I solved this by showing that all such matrices have a jordan form with that value for the determinant. But I expect there should be another less tedious method. Perhaps using Cayley-Hamilton theorem, but am unable to see how. Does anyone know how, or have seen a similar problem? (For $3 \times 3$ matrices, same constraints, $\det(A) = -1/4$.)

I came across this problem in Lovelock and Rund's book "Tensors, Differential Forms, and Variational Principles". It is problem 4.22 on page 129, but expressed using tensors. I think the authors expected a solution using generalised Kronecker deltas, but I got stuck,  so used standard matrices. Also, can matrices of that form be diagonalised? How to show that?

Comment: How *did* you solve it?

Comment: Well, very tediously!!  I let a, b, c, d be the main diagonal,  and for the supra-diagonal in Jordan form   I put 1,0,0  (from top left). Then I used the stated  conditions, set up the required equations and solved them.   There are eight  cases, some contradict the given conditions,  the others that are possible give det (A) = -16/27. Surely there is another way?

Comment: The two conditions imply that $x\ne0$ and the only possible eigenvalues of $A$ over $\mathbb C$ are the roots of the equation $x\lambda^2+\lambda-1=0$, namely $\lambda_\pm=\frac12\left(-\frac{1}{x}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{4}{x}}\right)$. Use the given conditions to argue that the spectrum of $A$ must be $\{\lambda_+,\lambda_+,\lambda_+,\lambda_-\}$ or $\{\lambda_-,\lambda_-,\lambda_-,\lambda_+\}$. The trace condition thus becomes $3\lambda_\pm+\lambda_\mp=0$, i.e.,
$$
\frac{2}{x}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{4}{x}}.
$$

Comment: ...Solve for $x$ and in turn obtain $x,\lambda_+$ and $\lambda_-$. Use the trace condition to find out which of $\{\lambda_+,\lambda_+,\lambda_+,\lambda_-\}$ or $\{\lambda_-,\lambda_-,\lambda_-,\lambda_+\}$ is the correct spectrum. Having determined the spectrum, you can compute the determinant.

Comment: @user1551 Why is it the case that the given polynomial is the characteristic one? We surely only have that the given polynomial is a minimal polynomial, so all the roots are eigenvalues, but there could be *more* eigenvalues since the minimal polynomial is not the characteristic one. Characteristic polynomial of a $4$ dimensional matrix needs to be of order $4$, right?

Comment: @FShrike The minimal polynomial must divide every annihilating polynomial. Therefore, the zeroes of the minimal polynomial is always a (possibly proper) subset of the zeroes of any given annihilating polynomial.

Comment: @user1551 A subset indeed. I don’t know how you’re concluding that the only possible eigenvalues of $A$ are the roots of $x\lambda^2+\lambda-1$, when these roots can only be said to be a subset of the spectrum rather than the whole spectrum itself...

Comment: My concern is that $x\lambda^2+\lambda-1$ is not the characteristic polynomial, so no conclusions can be made about *all* the eigenvalues. As in, you write $\Lambda=\{\lambda_+,\lambda_+,\lambda_-,\lambda_-\}$ for example, but for all we know it could be: $\Lambda=\{\lambda_+,\lambda_-,a,b\}$... @user1551

Comment: @FShrike Whether it is the characteristic polynomial (it isn't, because its degree is two) is unimportant. The key here is that it is an annihilating polynomial of $A$.

Comment: @FShrike See the [Wikipedia page for the minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) or [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101275/roots-of-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomials); there is a stronger relationship than what you are claiming.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you for that. It makes sense now that *all* the eigenvalues are roots of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for your comment. I did not know about minimal polynomials!  From your comment I can see that for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$  $(n > 2)$  with the given properties, and, say, $p$ positive entries on the main diagonal, it follows that $$ \det(A) = \frac{(2p-n)^{n} (-1)^{(n-p)}}{p^{p} (n-p)^{(n-p)}}$$ where $n-p \ne 0$ and $2p-n \ne 0$. For $n > 4$ the determinant values are not unique.

Comment: And the number of distinct values for $\det(A)$ is $\lfloor \frac{(n-1)}{2} \rfloor$.

Comment: A correction. In a previous comment, I should have said  " $p$ positive entries on the main diagonal of  a diagonal matrix similar to $A$".  Also $A$ can be diagonalised  since the minimal polynomial factors into distinct linear factors.