# To find minimal polynomial of a matrix

Tags: minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

I am asked to find the minimal polynomial of the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}  
4&-2&2\\  
6&-3&4\\  
3&-2&3\end{bmatrix}
I've calculated the characteristic polynomial is $\Delta(x)=(x-2)(x-1)^2$.
As we know that the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ must divide $\Delta(x)$, so the possibilities of being $m(x)$ are $(x-2),(x-1),(x-1)^2,(x-2)(x-1),(x-2)(x-1)^2$.
Among these, by Cayley-Hamilton theorem, for which least degree factor $\Delta(A)=O$ is satisfied will be the minimal polynomial.

But for some reason, the first three above mentioned factors were ignored in my book. What can be the possible reason for this?

Comment: If $v\neq0$  is an eigenvector of $T$ for the eigenvalue $r$, and $E=(v)$ is the subspace generated by $v$, then the minimal polynomial of $T|_E$ divides the minimal polynomial of $T$. This is because all polynomials $p$ such that $p(T)=0$ will also make $p(T_E)=0$. Since $T_E=rI$, the minimal polynomial of $T_E$ is $x-r$. Therefore, $x-r$ divides the minimal polynomial of $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because every root of the characteristic polynomial is always a root of the minimal polynomial. In the case, for instance, of $x-1$, $2$ is not a root, but it is a root of that characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Well, it's quite new to me. How can I prove it?

Comment: That's a standard Linear Algebra fact. You will find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/101275/446262).